# Nginx configuration file location on volumio

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, nginx

I installed volumio and would like to set up a .htaccess-like password prompt for its website. [This](https://volumio.org/forum/user-authentication-t2464.html) Forum Thread suggests that it should be possible. Unfortunately, since I'm neither the linux nor the nginx guy, I'm unable to find the config file. I guess he installed volumio on a Raspberry pi, I'm on a pc.
Does someone know what to do / where to find that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that volumio does not use nginx anymore. (https://volumio.org/forum/webui-password-protection-where-has-nginx-gone-t5994.html) That's why I wasn't able to find the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Type `nginx -V` and check for the compile parameter `--conf-path`.